# Cannot login to Docker account on macOS

Tags: macos, docker

Issue:

```
$ docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If 
you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to 
create one.
$ Username: jefftian
$ Password:
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: no 
credentials server URL, out: `no credentials server URL`
```

Analyse:

```
$ ls ~/.docker
config.json daemon.json machine

$ cat ~/.docker/config.json
{
  "auths" : {
    "unicareer.azurecr.io" : {

    },
    "https://unicareer.azurecr.io" : {

    }
  },
  "HttpHeaders" : {
    "User-Agent" : "Docker-Client/18.09.0 (darwin)"
  },
  "credSstore" : "osxkeychain",
  "stackOrchestrator" : "swarm",
  "credsStore" : "osxkeychain"
}
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

Oops it caused by my docker daemon not started.

Comment: Delete the post